# hidden iframe video moves around in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, embedding, vimeo

I have a slider with some images. When one image is clicked, the picture is removed and an iframe with an embedded vimeo video is added in it's place.

This works great everywhere except Safari. When you click it in Safari, the video appears down and almost halfway outside of the iframe, resulting in most of the video getting cut off. You can't see the controls, so you can't pause the video. But it still plays.

Why does it move like that. I want it to stay inside it's parent container like it does in FF and Chrome.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: 'slide',
    controlNav: false,
    slideshow: false,
    });

$("#iframeContainer").click(
     function () {
        $('#holdFrame').hide();
        var someText = '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/35534572?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;color=ffffff" width="960" height="540" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';
        var newDiv = $("<div>").append(someText);
            $(this).append(newDiv);
             }
        )       
   });
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
    <div id="iframeContainer">
         <img src="MotorolaStill_Patt.jpg" id="holdFrame" />
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <img src="MOTOROLA_BTS_01.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
    <img src="MOTOROLA_BTS_02.jpg" />    
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will just make it that you cant use it in safari, and so that it doesn't show up in safari, you will have to do this:

```
<!--
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: 'slide',
    controlNav: false,
    slideshow: false,
    });

$("#iframeContainer").click(
     function () {
        $('#holdFrame').hide();
        var someText = '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/35534572?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;color=ffffff" width="960" height="540" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';
        var newDiv = $("<div>").append(someText);
            $(this).append(newDiv);
             }
        )       
   });
-->
```

Comment: I mean, sure, but I would like it to work in Safari if at all possible.

Comment: Well, I dont have Safari so I'm not sure if there is a way